# Shopify liquid template debugging

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am trying to debug a Shopify theme.

I am a ruby dev, so understand the code.

But seems, if my liquid tags are in error than Shopify just ignores it/goes back to the previous version in production.

Any ideas how I can debug a live production theme's liquid template?

Comment: It is usually pretty hard to write erroneous Liquid and not generate an error message in the theme editor. If you write bad Liquid but it passes the basic sniff test for syntax, your output will reflect that it is botched. At that point you have to debug. What is the issue with that exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out, the view page source  shows Liquid Errors: in it

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help you or others coming to this question is using Shopify's [themekit](http://shopify.github.io/themekit/) for offline development. This will catch syntax errors on upload, for example:

```
    10:25:19 [development] Received Update event on templates/product.liquid
    10:25:19 [development]Asset Perform Update to templates/product.liquid at host yourshop.myshopify.com
    Status: 422 Unprocessable Entity
    Errors: Liquid syntax error (line 7): Unknown tag 'not_a_tag'
```

There is a good, though slightly outdated now, tutorial [here](https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Advanced-Shopify-Theme-Development/708093439). To note, when he mentions downloading the shopify_theme gem, that is now not maintained and you should use themekit instead.